# NestJS library is not being imported

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I created a nest js library using cli.
I also build the library first, however when I try to import it as module. it is unable to identify it.

```
Cannot find module '@app/big-query' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

All the code is auto generated so I was assuming I only have to import it. as it is described in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check nest-cli.json if library was created, typically it looks like this

```
"common": {
  "type": "library",
  "root": "libs/common",
  "entryFile": "index",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/common/src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "tsConfigPath": "libs/common/tsconfig.lib.json"
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it was created.